# No correct output

Tags: tikz-pgf

After installation of the last version of MiKTeX and TikZ, I created following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
The version of Tikz is : \pgfversion
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After running of "Build and running current file" with TeXnicCenter I received as answer:

```
LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s),  0 Warning(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 1 Page(s)
BibTex-Result: 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s)
```

and as output :

- "The version of TikZ is 2.10"
- as drawing a set of four curved lines wich intersect each other but no circle at all.

Could some body help me please?

P.S. I'm working under Windows XP 32-bit.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, you can format code sections by indenting by four spaces, or highlight ad use the `{}` button, see my edit.

Comment: Your document seems to work for me.  What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Try to run `pdflatex` instead of using the build button.

Comment: Could you upload somewhere a screenshot of your result and post the link? We can paste the image in the question for you.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: If you don't know how to make a screenshot, do the following: (1) make sure your image active (on view), (2) locate the Print Screen button (at top row and right after the F12 key), press it once, (3) open PaintBrush (mspaint.exe), (4) paste to it, (5) save as PNG, (6) upload to this site.